# Jquery doesn't work on IE9

Tags: jquery, browser

I use a jquery table add row plugin on my web page, and it works fine on my local desktop on Chrome and IE9.

But when I uploaded the project to the server, it still work fine on Chrome, but nothing happened on IE9, (there is a addrow button, when i click it, no row was added).

do you have any idea why this happen?

I use the latest jquery version.

edit:

```
 <table id="tblotherlicence" style="width:800px" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="3">     
        <tr><td class="formtitle" colspan="5">OTHER PROFESSIONAL LICENSURE<a style="font-size:7pt">(e.g.,registered psychiatric nurse; registered massage therapist; registered social worker)</a></td></tr>
        <tr><td class="formlabel">Profession</td>
            <td class="formlabel">Licence Number</td>
            <td class="formlabel">Jurisdiction</td>
            <td class="formlabel">Date of Expiry</td>
            <td class="formlabel"><input class="addrow" type="button" value="Add Row" /></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="Licence1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="LicenceNumber1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="Jurisdiction1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td><asp:TextBox ID="ExpiryDate1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td><input class="delrow" type="button" value="Delete Row" /></td>
        </tr>
     </table> 

 <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#<%=ExpiryDate1.ClientID%>").datepicker({
                        yearRange: '1950:2015',
                        changeYear: true, 
                        changeMonth: true,
      257        });
                $(".addrow").btnAddRow(function () {
                    var i;
                    var rowCount = $("#tblotherlicence tr").length;
                    for (i = 3; i <= rowCount; i++) {
                        $("#tblotherlicence tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(4) input[type='text']").attr("id", "MainPlaceHolder_RecordofNursing1_ExpiryDate" + (i - 2));            
                        $("#tblotherlicence tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(4) input[type='text']").removeAttr("class");
                        $("#tblotherlicence tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(4) input[type='text']").datepicker({
                                yearRange: '1950:2015',
                                changeYear: true, 
                                changeMonth: true,
                        });
                    }
                });
                $(".delrow").btnDelRow();
            }); 
    </script>
```

the error is "SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number xxxxx.aspx, line 257 character 21",  I have marked the line 257 which is just a close bracket

Comment: Hi, Pita. Always show code when asking a question.

Comment: Post a jsFiddle of your code or some code samples. Maybe a URL to a page where it's happening?

Comment: What kind of server?  Check the browser for js error messages.  Also, make sure the feature that is not working is supported in ie9

Comment: We need more details than just this.  What plugin are you using?  Have you tried clearing IE's cache?  Were there any errors in the console?

Comment: Too hard to help you without seeing any code. Most likely there's an error in your code somewhere — it might even be some other script breaking.

Show us how you include the script and what your function looks like.

Comment: why it works fine on my own computer but not on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the trailing comma after `changeMonth`

```
$("#<%=ExpiryDate1.ClientID%>").datepicker({
   yearRange: '1950:2015',
   changeYear: true, 
   changeMonth: true // Right here
});
```

"Expected identifier, string or number" means that it receives something different that it's supposed to. In this case, as you have a comma, it expects more stuff to come after `changeMonth`, but instead you close it.

Some browsers tend to be very lenient on typos and small errors like this, but IE is more strict. This can be a good thing (enforces correct code), but it also means you'll experience more errors.

Answer (score 0):

This "problem" is not specific to jQuery.  IE doesn't like trailing commas in object declarations, while other browsers will ignore it.

I'd recommend running your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) to catch errors like this.  You'll probably get much better error messages than what you get in IE9, as well.  And you'll have much cleaner code!